# Networkx shortest path with condition on edges - python

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

Let's consider the following `Graph`:

```py
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), ('A', 'C', {'metro': 4, 'time': 4}), ('A', 'D', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), 
                  ('C', 'E', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), ('D', 'E', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), ('B', 'F', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), 
                  ('D', 'F', {'metro': 4, 'time': 4}), ('E', 'F', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3})])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_color='white')
```

Three attributes can be seen for edges:

- `walk` is the time taken to walk for one stop to the other (when it is possible).
- `metro` is the time taken to go from a stop to the other by taking the subway.
- `time` is equal to `walk` or `metro` and is the weight I use for `nx.shortest_path` (that allows my to get the path that takes the less time by not having to either chose between subway or walking).

I now would like to get the `nx.shortest_path(G, 'A', 'F', weight='time')` between nodes `A` and `F` with a condition on the path: I want to have the `shortest_path` with the less `walk` edges as possible.

In this case, the only `shortest_path` considered as good would be `A -> D -> F` since there is only 1 `walk` edge while the others have at least two (even though the total `time` for some edges are shorter).

Is there a way to do that?

---

**Edit:** I tried using `nx.all_shortest_paths()` to get several `shortest_paths` and then select the one that fits my requirements but it does not work. `nx.all_shortest_paths()` indeed gives me a higher amount of short paths possible between a `source` and a `target` however all of them already have too many `walk edges` in them.
A solution would be to get what are considered to be the `shortest of shortest paths` and the one that are less short to maybe have more choice.
I, however, have no ideas how I should be going about this.

Comment: Could you penalize your walk edges by multiplying time by 10?  The calculate shortest path?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. The path I get is still equivalent to the one I have with regular ```walk``` edges but it takes longer to go form the ```source``` to the ```target``` while keeping a huge amount of ```walk``` edges in it.

Answer (score 2):

Using your example:

Original network less "walk penalty":

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), ('A', 'C', {'metro': 4, 'time': 4}), ('A', 'D', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), 
                  ('C', 'E', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), ('D', 'E', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), ('B', 'F', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3}), 
                  ('D', 'F', {'metro': 4, 'time': 4}), ('E', 'F', {'walk': 3, 'time': 3})])
#nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_color='white')
nx.shortest_path(G, 'A', 'F', weight='time')
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'F']
```

Now, let's penalize walk edges times by multiplying 10x:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B', {'walk': 3, 'time': 30}), ('A', 'C', {'metro': 4, 'time': 4}), ('A', 'D', {'walk': 3, 'time': 30}), 
                  ('C', 'E', {'walk': 3, 'time': 30}), ('D', 'E', {'walk': 3, 'time': 30}), ('B', 'F', {'walk': 3, 'time': 30}), 
                  ('D', 'F', {'metro': 4, 'time': 4}), ('E', 'F', {'walk': 3, 'time': 30})])
#nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_color='white')
nx.shortest_path(G, 'A', 'F', weight='time')
```

Output:

```
['A', 'D', 'F']
```

Can you provide an example where this will not work, if you penalize your "walk" edges enough?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to keep the post simple but I guess it's too simple now... :/ The best solution would be to share the ```Graph``` I am using but it's very massive. I will create a simplified subgraph containing a specific example of what is not working and edit my post + answer to let you know.

Comment: @I.M. You might need to adjust your multiplication factor to get enough penalty on "walk" edges.  10x might not be enough.